# How can I have a copy of this old paper?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

How can I have a copy of this old paper and a translation of it?

Frobenius, G. (1902). Uber primitive Gruppen des Grades n und der Klasse n - 1. S. B. Akad. Berlin 1902, 455-459.

Comment: Download Link: http://goo.gl/pDkRi6

Comment: Online: https://ia902309.us.archive.org//load_djvu_applet.php?file=0/items/sitzungsberichte1902deutsch/sitzungsberichte1902deutsch.djvu

Comment: I started a meta thread about this closure: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/help-me-find-a-paper-type-questions

Comment: Funny, it got an answer on MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/185045/how-can-i-have-a-copy-of-this-old-paper